# How to Trace Object Boundary Points in Order in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I need to get the set of points `{(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),....(xn,yn)}` where this set represents the boundary points **AND** `(xk,yk)` and `(xk+1, yk+1)` are neighbors. So clearly I need to get the boundary points in order to use in Fourier descriptors.

I used bwboundaries and bwtraceboundary and they both gave poor results, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You mean, like in an image? Be more precise please, in order for people to understand your problem and help you.

Comment: In order means that point x-1 is a neighbor of point x which is a neighbor of point x+1 , all these points are contour point !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bwtraceboundary()` should do exactly what you want. Take a look at this example:

```
x = imread('rice.png');
xCropped = x(75:93, 100:140);
figure; imshow(xCropped);

xBW = xCropped>175;
b = bwtraceboundary(xBW, [8 8], 'E');

hold on;
plot(b(:,2),b(:,1));
```

Comment: I realize that he said bwtraceboundary wasn't working for him, but I see no reason why. It does exactly what he is asking for.

Comment: that's true, downvote removed. I bet he's trying it on an image with poor initial filtering

Comment: @AK4749 Thanks! I edited the answer, maybe you can remove the downvote now?